# How to create a function which replace an empty values with the most appearing value or average value based on the specific columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

A csv file contains more than 18 columns and I want to perform data cleaning without dropping rows with empty values.

Some columns have string while other have float and int so I want to create function that will automatically check a certain columns with an empty value and replace that empty with either the most appearing value if this is string based column and the average value for int and float based columns instead of doing it manually.

```
|response|score|
|A       |25   |
|A       |     |
|B       |20   |
|C       |15   |
|        |25   |
```

My sample codes

```
df['response']=df['response'].fillna('A').astype(str)
df['score']=df['score'].fillna(df.score.mean()).astype(float)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a custom function with [`pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.api.types.is_numeric_dtype.html):

```
def filler(s):
    if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(s):
        fill_value = s.mean()
    else:                         # add other conditions if needed
        fill_value = s.mode()[0]
    return s.fillna(fill_value)

out = df.apply(filler)
```

As a one-liner

```
out = df.apply(lambda s: s.fillna(s.mean() if pd.api.types.is_numeric_dtype(s)
                                  else s.mode()[0]))
```

Output:

```
  response  score
0        A  25.00
1        A  21.25
2        B  20.00
3        C  15.00
4        A  25.00
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
df['score'] = df['score'].fillna(df.groupby('response')['score'].transform('mean'))
```

This will replace the nulls with mean of values of the same 'response'.

You can change the function to median, max, min - depends on your use case

If you want to do that for all the columns:

```
for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].fillna(df.groupby('response')[col].transform('mean'))
```

Comment: what if I have more than one columns for example not only score column but also another columns with either float or int value so from this case I will  add another line of code below right? this is not good for me I want single block of code to perform for all column either float or int based type, please read a detailed body above

Comment: What about the column with string or object value how do you fill the most appearing value because the above work for float and int datatype

Comment: This depends on the use case. What is an appropriate value for these columns?

Comment: see on the response column we have A which appear 2 times, comparing to B AND C values, So the A value should replace an empty value you see there below, other columns may have different value but all are string/ object so we do the same action with a single function not duplicating line of code for example if other column is called 'newcolumn; with value D,D,'', G,F,H e replace D on empty value

Comment: For strings you could use MEDIAN - i.e. to replace with the most common value